# restrict node.js restful api access

Tags: node.js, api, restful-architecture, restrict

I would like to restrict client access to my restful node.js APIs. I'm about to create two different interfaces, an android app and a angular.js web app. All other third-party applications should not be authorize to use the APIs. I was thinking about something like Google Developers Code, registering a code for each authorized app, and storing/hiding somewhere/somehow in the app.

Ps. the restful server is under **HTTPS** and i'm not dealing with user authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd look at using a framework such as [Passport](http://passportjs.org/guide/oauth2-api/) to implement an OAuth2 solution.

Comment: But oauth i for user authentication. I would like to identify the client that a user is using, i.e. a CLI, web app, android or ios app etc

Comment: OAuth is for client *authorisation*.  The client is an application or server not a user, in OAuth the user is known as the Resource Owner.  OAuth has got nothing to do with user authentication.  That's what OpenID Connect is for, which happens to sit on top of OAuth2.

Comment: ok, i got it :)
But what type of authorization should i use? Implicit grant?